# Why would pgrep not show my processes but sudo pgrep does?

Tags: process, ps, ssh-agent

I looked at a list of processes and filtered out `ssh-agent` which correctly shows the 3 processes I expected:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ssh-agent
belmin   1051     1  0 16:05 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
belmin   2569     1  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
belmin   2655     1  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
belmin   5093  2596  0 16:17 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color ssh-agent
```

However, if I perform a `pgrep`, it doesn't list the 3 processes unless I escalate to `sudo`:

```
$ pgrep -a ssh-agent

$ sudo !!
sudo pgrep -a ssh-agent
1051 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
2569 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
2655 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
```

Initially, I thought it was because PPID is 1. However, this isn't a problem with other processes that have PPID as 1 so that's not it.

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

So apparently applying namespace argument (`--ns`) works without `sudo`---regardless of what namespace I provide:

```
$ for n in 'ipc' 'mnt' 'net' 'pid' 'user' 'uts'; do echo pgrep -a --ns $n ssh-agent; pgrep -a --ns $n ssh-agent; done
    pgrep -a --ns ipc ssh-agent
    12986 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
    pgrep -a --ns mnt ssh-agent
    12986 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
    pgrep -a --ns net ssh-agent
    12986 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
    pgrep -a --ns pid ssh-agent
    12986 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
    pgrep -a --ns user ssh-agent
    12986 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
    pgrep -a --ns uts ssh-agent
    12986 ssh-agent -a /home/belmin/.ssh/.auth_sock.pineapple
```

Still unclear as to why. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Please show what `type pgrep` shows?

Comment: `pgrep is hashed (/usr/bin/pgrep)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procps 3.3.13 had pgrep filter on namespaces. Mainly so pkill doesn't kill outside it's namespace. However for some processes, especially around SSH for some reason, it gives odd results.

3.3.14 has this change reverted.

Comment: Ah, I see the change the [commit that caused this](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/dcb6914f11406a13972636b08b7e26fdafe9efc9). Looks like it is indeed reverted in 3.3.14. Thanks for leading me to this.

Answer (score 2):

You may have the `/proc` filesystem mounted with option `hidepid` set. This is a security feature to protect information from other users on the system. See the `man` page for `proc` for full information. You can check whether this is the case by performing `grep proc /etc/mtab` and seeing whether the result includes `hidepid=2`. You can change the setting by modifying file `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: It works, but it also hide output from `ps -ef`. In the question `ps -ef` isn't hidden.